# Negative margin bottom to footer doesn't work

Tags: css, html

I'm trying to move the footer down 50px to go outta screen,
but the negative margin doesn't work (nothing is moving) and I'm not quite sure why...

```
footer {
  background: #111;
  padding: 50px 0 100px;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}
```

Here's an example

```css
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
}

footer {
  background: green;
  padding: 50px 0 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <section>
    Section 1
  </section>

  <section>
    Section 2
  </section>

  <footer>
    <div>
      some content here
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>
```

Comment: please, add a snippet with your code, then we can see what's the problem

Comment: Try `margin-top:50px`

Comment: @ZohirSalak That only adds space on top of the footer. What I'm trying to do is to move down 50px of the footer to go out of the screen at the bottom

Comment: @mthrsj Can you elaborate? I've already added the footer css

Comment: A negative bottom margin will not "pull" a static footer down. Please add an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (as @mthrsj) requested with the relevant code so we can see what the issue is. Without context, we can only guess.

Comment: @Tina it doesn't add space on top of it, it actually pushes it down, however if it causes overflow then scrollbars will be introduced, if there's already scrollbars it will appear as if we added a space on top.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Negative margin is working fine but it's not doing what you are expecting. negative margin-bottom will not make the element to move outside. It will make the parent element to shrink instead.

Here is a simplifed example:

```css
.box {
  border:5px solid #000;
}
.box div{
  background:red;
  height:200px;
  margin-bottom:-50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

As you can see the parent element has a height less than its child due to negative margin and we are having an overflow.

This is what is happening in your case, and since the overflow is by default scroll you will keep seeing the footer. Add some border and you will better see:

```css
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  border:2px solid;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
}

footer {
  background: green;
  padding: 50px 0 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: -50px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    Section 1
  </section>

  <section>
    Section 2
  </section>

  <footer>
    <div>
      some content here
    </div>
  </footer>
```

In order to hide the overflowing part, simply adjust the overflow property and you will have what you want:

```css
html {
 overflow:auto;
}

body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  border:2px solid;
  overflow:hidden;
}

section {
  height: 100vh;
}

footer {
  background: green;
  padding: 50px 0 100px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  margin-bottom: -200px;
}
```

```html
<section>
    Section 1
  </section>

  <section>
    Section 2
  </section>

  <footer>
    <div>
      some content here
    </div>
  </footer>
```

As you can see, I have added a bigger negative margin to shrink more the body element and to make all the footer outside then I hide it using `overflow:hidden`

Comment: TL;DR; `html{overflow:auto} body{overflow:hidden}`

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question right, you want a footer to be half hidden from the view.

If so, try to use fixed position, add this to your `css`:

```
position: fixed;
bottom: -50px;
```

Answer (score 0):

use transform instead of margin 
`footer {transform: translateY(-50px);}`

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Firefox, try hitting the F12 button for the Web Developer tool.
In the inspector tab you can inspect the element and set the css rules for that element.

Probably you have some kind of conflict with rules declared somewhere else. 
You can change live the css for testing in the Web Developer -> Inspector -> Stiles.

Answer (score -1):

For positioning use position and top/bottom/left/right. For example

```
position: relative;
bottom:50px;
```